# Locked file texture in Maya shadingNode

Tags: python, textures, maya, shading

I am getting some strange results here using the `shadingNode`, whenever I create a file node through Python in Maya I get the color space locked and the color space drop menu greyed out.

```
fileNode = cmds.shadingNode( "file", asTexture=True, name="dispMap" )
```

Please see image attached, however I get the usual expected result when I create the file node from the create shader tab in `Hypershade`.

[Here's an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2nXg5.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to re-apply the `Input Color Space Rules`.

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
import pymel.core as pm

shader = cmds.shadingNode( 'anisotropic', asShader=True )
file_node = cmds.shadingNode( 'file', asTexture=True, name="dispMap" )
# file = ( '/Users/me/Desktop/texture.jpg' )

shading_group = cmds.sets( renderable=True, noSurfaceShader=True, empty=True )
cmds.connectAttr( '%s.outColor' %shader , '%s.surfaceShader' %shading_group )
cmds.connectAttr( '%s.outColor' %file_node, '%s.color' %shader )

cmds.polySphere( n='mySphere', radius=5, sx=40, sy=30 )
cmds.select( 'mySphere', visible=True )
cmds.hyperShade( assign=shader )

colMgmtGlob = pm.PyNode( 'defaultColorMgtGlobals' )

for f in pm.ls( type='file' ):
    colMgmtGlob.cmEnabled >> f.colorManagementEnabled
    colMgmtGlob.configFileEnabled >> f.colorManagementConfigFileEnabled
    colMgmtGlob.configFilePath >> f.colorManagementConfigFilePath
    colMgmtGlob.workingSpaceName >> f.workingSpace
```

Answer (score 1):

Perfect, it worked as it should after setting the file format to 'Raw' in my case, thanks Andy.

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
import pymel.core as pm

fileNode = cmds.shadingNode("file",asTexture=True, name = "dispMap") 

def InputColorRules():
    colMgmtGlob = pm.PyNode( 'defaultColorMgtGlobals' )
    for f in pm.ls( type='file' ):
        colMgmtGlob.cmEnabled >> f.colorManagementEnabled
        colMgmtGlob.configFileEnabled >> f.colorManagementConfigFileEnabled
        colMgmtGlob.configFilePath >> f.colorManagementConfigFilePath
        colMgmtGlob.workingSpaceName >> f.workingSpace
        cmds.setAttr('%s.colorSpace' %f, 'Raw', type='string')

InputColorRules()
```